# Merge First name with Last name using Applescript

Tags: applescript, contacts

I'm using MacBook. In the application "Contacts", I've managed the people's name like this. The first name is in the first name field, the Last name is in last name field. But now I want to change this format. First name and last name together is in the First name field and not using Last name field.

In my contacts, I have more than 1,000 contacts' information. If I do this task one by one with my hand, it will take too much time. So, I want to make Applescript do this task automatically. But unfortunately, I do not know the grammar of Applescript. Please help me to handle this job easily without time wasting.

Comment: Easily without time wasting = someone write the code for me?

Answer (score 0):

*insert sigh here*
If this wasn't AppleScript, a language that's syntax is pretty much all english words, I would understand if you don't understand the syntax.
It's a really easy language to understand because of this.
**Back to the question**,
Doing a [Google search for "Change contacts with AppleScript"](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=change+contacts+with+applescript), the first result is [this](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/bulk-edit-address-book-contacts.php).
In less than 3 minutes, without any prior knowledge to automating Contacts, I put together a short script that does what you've asked for.
The first code snippet on [the page](http://www.macosxtips.co.uk/index_files/bulk-edit-address-book-contacts.php) is all I needed,

```
tell application "Address Book"
    set peopleToChange to people whose (street of first address) contains "321 Old Street"
    repeat with thePerson in peopleToChange
        set (street of first address) of thePerson to "123 New Street"
    end repeat
    save
end tell
```

All I had to do was use common sense to know that "first name" and "last name" would be the property to automate them.
I just changed the name of the properties and what I was doing with them using this code snippet, and the result:

```
tell application "Contacts"
    set peopleToChange to people whose (last name) is not equal to ""
    repeat with thePerson in peopleToChange
        set first name of thePerson to first name of thePerson & " " & (last name) of thePerson
        set (last name) of thePerson to ""
    end repeat
    save
end tell
```

I've tested it, and it works.
For the future, spend more time trying before asking a question, you'll get negative reputation.